# Macbook Air freezes while running Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: macbook-air

Ok folks I'm trying to setup my Macbook Air to run Ubuntu 13.10 (note: I normally using Kubuntu but currently running Ubuntu).  I have run all of the updates for the system as of this posting.
This happens regardless of the application I have open (Firefox, Terminal, Software Updater).

The system will freeze, become unresponsive and then kick me back to the login screen. I don't see a crash notification or anything to send as troubleshooting so I don't know where to start

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all.  THe linked answer tells me things to "unlock" my system a lot of the times.  In fact nothing  in the linked post talks about this happening every time specifically in regards to a Mac.

Comment: Also this freeze seems to be related to the mouse?  I have been presented an apport crash and have tried to work through it but after clicking on the mouse the system freezes for a bit and kicks me back to login prompt.

Comment: Finally got the crash data to report correctly and posted it as this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1247510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same freezing issue with Ubuntu 13.10 and my Macbook Air 3,2.  It seems the culprit was whatever display driver was installed by default. Doing the following seems to have fixed it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331
```

Comment: thanks been a bit since i tried it but this worked so i marked it as the solution